# How to read text from a specific line, compare with another line and display

Tags: vb.net

I've searched and found similar topics but none that really answer my question, or perhaps it's the fact that I'm a beginner and I don't fully understand yet.

What I'm trying to do is use a ComboBox and a TextBox. Once the ComboBox selection changes, the TextBox will load more information about the item in the ComboBox. This is for my company, trying to store canned messages with a title.

So I want to have a title for these messages in a ComboBox drop-down, and once a title is chosen, the message is displayed in the TextBox. Right now, I've got the message creation, which is also part of my program, appending to two different text files, since I'm not sure yet on how to append data from two controls onto the same line and concatenate a Tab or other delimiter.

So my question is, what method should I be going about doing this? The part I am REALLY not understanding is how to get the line number value from the selected item in the TextBox, they load just fine using the following line:

```
savedmsgComboBox.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines("MessageListTitles.txt"))
```

So how do I get which line this selection is on, and how do I correspond that line with the message I need to display in the TextBox?

Comment: Where does the other info come from once an item is selected?

Comment: Right now it's just coming from another text file in same directory, "MessageList.txt"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will only work if both arrays have the same amount of lines. Load both files into arrays.

```
'declare the arrays
Private msgTitles() As String
Private msgList() As String 

'in load event fill them
msgTitles = File.ReadAllLines("MessageListTitles.txt")
msgList = File.ReadAllLines("MessageList.txt")

'load the combobox 
savedmsgComboBox.Items.AddRange(msgTitles)

'get the items by the index
Dim msgListItem As String = msgList(savedmsgComboBox.SelectedIndex)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked great! I've got everything running smoothly now.